# "read-only file system" error when writing to SD card

Tags: android, eclipse

Failed to push selection: Read-only file system
this error comes when i am trying to add any file in sdcard of emulator..can any one tell me what is the solution of it?

Comment: Does your app have external storage rights?

Comment: no i don't have external storage..i just want to show my file in emulator sd card.That Means i want to push file in sd card from my desktop..when i tried to do same thing in another pc that is working fine..but in my pc it shows the error.

Comment: external link does not work! blog removed

Answer (score -1, accepted):

i solved it...refer this link: http://daraizetechnologies.blogspot.in/2011/06/how-to-mount-sdcard-in-android-emulator.html it contains step by step guide to it..i had to create new sd card image and than in run configuration i gave path to that sd card and now i am able to put files on sd card..that link was useful

Answer (score 4):

You need to grant your app permission to write to the external SD card. It's not important that you're in the "emulator", the emulator IS Android, so it needs to have the same rights as if it were running on an actual device.
Add this line to your manifest...

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

And you'll be good to go.

Comment: hi! i solved it...refer this link:http://daraizetechnologies.blogspot.com/2011/06/how-to-mount-sdcard-in-android-emulator.html it contains step by step guide to it..i had to create new sd card image and than in run configuration i gave path to that sd card and now i am able to put files on sd card..that link was useful

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem; The reason appeared to be that the sdcard was not given a size.

By opening the 'Android Virtual Device Manager' and edit the device, I could alter the size of the sdcard, or at least make sure that it is not blanc (as that was my problem). After saving the alterations and a reboot of both the emulator and in my case alse Eclipse, the read/write permissions were set correct and I could add files to the sdcard in the emulator.

Comment: Worked perfectly in Android Studio.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that you have added `SDCard` to your Emulator. So, you should make sure that your AVD should have the `SD Card Support - yes`

Answer (score 0):

I experienced distressing Android external SD read/write error. 
The work around was to check file errors: 
Popped the SD card in to my Windows phone, and error gone..!

Answer (score 0):

What solved this for me was, as said creating my own sd card file. The steps are as follows

1. Create sdcard `android/sdk/tools/mksdcard [size] [file]`
2. And attach the file as external file under sdcard (shown in advanced setting). **Note:** this sometimes doesn't work. if it doesn't go to **~/.android/avd/[device].avd/config.ini** and set **sdcard** to the generated file